# How to customize the numbering in fitch.sty natural deduction proofs?

Tags: proofs

I'm using the `fitch.sty` package for natural deduction proofs, but I'd like to add a period after the line number, e.g., 1. versus "1". I looked into the documentation but found nothing that allows me to customize the numbers. The documentation does, in fact, state the following: "In the output, lines are automatically numbered consecutively. Labels may not contain any
punctuation characters or spaces." Since they are generated automatically, is there any way I can alter the generation to include periods after the numbering?

Comment: Please show us what you tra so far.

Comment: Try `\expandafter\def\csname nd*numo\endcsname#1#2{\edef\x{#1}\mbox{$\x.$}\expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname nd*-#2\endcsname\x}` in your preamble.

Comment: My previous comment is based on this [package](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/fitch/) by Peter Selinger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to modify `\formatfitchcounter`. I assume it is

```
% $Id: fitch.sty,v 1.6 2003/06/28 16:53:00 johanw Exp $

% Macros for Fitch-style formal proofs
% Johan W. Klüwer, June 10, 2001
```

(possibly with a different release date).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fitch}

\renewcommand{\formatfitchcounter}[1]{\arabic{#1}.}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{fitch}
\fh \lnot (A \land B)  \\
\fa A \lor \lnot A \\
\fa\fh A \\
\fa\fa\fh B \\
\fa\fa\fa A \land B & 3, 4 \\
\fa\fa\fa \bot & 1, 5 \\
\fa\fa \lnot B & 4--6 \\
\fa\fa \lnot A \lor \lnot B & 7 \\
\fa A \to (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) & 3--8 \\
\fa\fh \lnot A \\
\fa\fa \lnot A \lor \lnot B & 10 \\
\fa \lnot A \to (\lnot A \lor \lnot B)  & 10--11\\
\fa \lnot A \lor \lnot B & 2, 9, 12 \\
\lnot (A \land B)\to (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) & 1--13 \\
\fh \lnot A \lor \lnot B \\
\end{fitch}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Congratulations! You have found the correct version of this package! :-)